# Call template file, hook_theme() thru theme( hook, $data )

Tags: theming

I am trying to call a template file but without luck.

```
   /**
     * Implements hook_theme().
     */
    function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      return array(
        'my_module_text' => array(
          'template' => 'my_module_text',
          'variables' => array(
               'myvar' => 'helloworld'
           ),
          'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module'),
        ),
      );
    }


    /**
     * Preprocessor for theme('my_module_text').
     */ 
    function my_module_preprocess_my_module_text(&$variables) {
      debug('text preprocessor called');
    }
```

I have a template file in the module directory named my_module_text.tpl.php.

When I call `theme('my_module_text',array('myvar' => 'helloworld'));` I get nothing. The template file is not used.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me; make sure you've cleared Drupal's caches since implementing `hook_theme()`, and your preprocess function, as these implementations are cached, and won't show up in the registry until you do.

FYI, the "path" property is not required if the template file resides in your module's folder: Drupal will check there first anyway (this won't be causing the problem though).

Comment: yeah, it looks right to me too. Thanks for the tip of regarding path! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can see with what done, for example, in [taxonomy_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_theme/7) is the name of the template file.

```
function taxonomy_theme() {
  return array(
    'taxonomy_overview_vocabularies' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ), 
    'taxonomy_overview_terms' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ), 
    'taxonomy_term' => array(
      'render element' => 'elements', 
      'template' => 'taxonomy-term',
    ),
  );
}
```

For what I recall the name of the template file reported in `hook_theme()` must match the array index used in the returned array, with the only difference being using a hyphen instead of an underscore (as hyphens are not allowed in PHP function names).

I am not sure that using underscores in the template file names could cause any issue; [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) uses the template name returned from `hook_theme()`, but there could code in Drupal that changes the underscore in the template filename with hyphens.

```
// Render the output using the template file.
$template_file = $info['template'] . $extension;
if (isset($info['path'])) {
  $template_file = $info['path'] . '/' . $template_file;
}
$output = $render_function($template_file, $variables);
```

Even [theme_render_template()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_render_template/7), the function that in Drupal 7 renders a template file, doesn't change the template filename.

```
  extract($variables, EXTR_SKIP); // Extract the variables to a local namespace
  ob_start(); // Start output buffering
  include DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $template_file; // Include the template file
  return ob_get_clean(); // End buffering and return its contents
```

If you are altering a theme that is currently enabled, you need to clear the Drupal cache as Drupal caches information about the enabled themes, in the same way it does with the list of hooks implemented by modules.